# How do you access Windows Command Line Arguments?

Tags: windows, assembly, command-line

I have been doing some Windows Assembly Language programming lately and I realized that I don't know how to access the Command Line parameters. I have searched online but I haven't found anything about it.(Perhaps I do not know how to phrase the question) Is Window's method of passing the parameters from the command line to the program the same as how Linux does it? What I mean by this is **ebp** initially set to point to argc?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) retrieves a pointer to the unparsed command-line.

[CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parses the command-line into an array of arguments.  There isn't an ANSI version.